# left shift error

Tags: c++, c

I have an `unsigned long long` variable which is 8 bytes on my system which I'm trying to do the following on:

```
unsigned long long ull;
ull = timeLow;
ull |= timeHigh << 32;
```

I get a warning of: left shift count >= width of type when doing this. Also it doesn't seem to take into account the timeHigh shifted in. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why system is this (hardware/OS/compiler)? Any reason for not using uint64_t?

Comment: Try `ull |= timeHigh << 32ull;` Note the suffix on the number.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Doesn't help, since `<<` does not perform the usual arithmetic conversions; the left operand (after default promotions) must be big enough.

Answer (score 10):

You're not shifting `ull`, you're shifiting `timeHigh`, and then storing the results of that shift in `ull`.

I suspect that `timeHigh` is not big enough to store the reults of a 32-bit shift.  Make `timeHigh` an `unsigned long long`, (**edit**) or alternatively just assign `timeHigh` to `ull`  and then shift that before `or`'ing in `timeLow`. (credit @JasonD)

Comment: Or alternatively just assign timeHigh to ull first, and then shift that before or'ing in timeLow.

Answer (score 0):

timeHigh seems to be a 32 bit type. after leftshifting by 32 bits it is all zeros. you have to convert timeHigh to a type long long before shifting.

```
unsigned long long ull;
ull = timeHigh;
ull = ull << 32;
ull |= timeLow;
```

Comment: Left-shifting a 32-bit unsigned number by 32 bits results in Undefined Behavior, not necessarily "all zeros".

Comment: i described what probably happened in his special case 'it doesn't seem to take into account the timeHigh shifted in'. you are right, i should have mentioned the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
unsigned long long timeLow = /* value */;
unsigned long long timeHigh = /* value */;
unsigned long long ull;
ull = (timeHigh << 32 | timeLow)
```