# Fixed point arithmetic long long int representation issue in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I am struggling with the realization of a signed long long int variable having the value 1 set in its integer part.
Looking at the 16.16 implementation with a signed long int variable it does work like this:

```
static signed long int varInit = 1 << 16; /* alternatively: 65536 */
unsigned short int integer_part,fractional_part;
fractional_part = ((unsigned short int *) &varInit)[0];
integer_part = ((unsigned short int *) &varInit)[1];
```

This leads to the following representation: `0001.0000`

Unfortunately I cannot get it to work in the 32.32 representation:

```
static signed long long int varInit = 1 << 32;
unsigned long int integer_part,fractional_part;
fractional_part = ((unsigned long int *) &varInit)[0];
integer_part = ((unsigned long int *) &varInit)[1];
```

I get the following gcc warning:
`warning: left shift count >= width of type`

What am I getting wrong?

I am trying to get the following representation: `00000001.00000000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [left shift error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937598/left-shift-error)

Comment: Note that `((unsigned short int *) &varInit)[0]` breaks strict aliasing, and thus will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: `1 << 32` is undefined if `int` is 32 bits. Please use `1LL << 32`.

Comment: `((unsigned short int *) &varInit)[0]` that is invalid. Just use `varInit >> 16` if you mean that. `What am I getting wrong?` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule and just use union.

Comment: I can think of three ways of extracting the integer and fractional parts of a fixed-point representation: (1) using `/` and `%`, (2) using shifting and masking, and (3) using pointers.  Method 1 has the advantage that it works for any fixed-point precision, not just powers of two.  Method 2 has the advantage that might be more efficient.  Method 3 is probably also efficient, but it has a couple of significant disadvantages: it's not as obvious how it works, it likely suffers from byte order issues,  and it can suffer from other issues as well, like strict aliasing.  So I don't recommend #3.

Comment: (With that said, though, your problem wasn't because you used method 3, but because of the way you set your initial value up, using shifting, and the problem you had there can pretty easily befall method 2 as well.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your helpful comments. I do really appreciate that my question has been answered honestly, with that much input, the good old way.

Comment: Side question: in your 16.16 representation, you noted that 65536 corresponded to `0001.0000`.  What would 65537 correspond to?  `0001.0001`, or 1.0000152587890625?  That is, how do you intend to use `integer_part` and `fractional_part` to form an actual fraction?

Comment: @SteveSummit: Right, 0001.0001 is the representation I am using for 65537. The printed result will actually have base 16 (e.g.: 0004.F3E3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression

```
1 << 32
```

has undefined behavior because the operands have the type `int` and the result also has the type `int`.

From the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
> type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value
> of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the
> width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined**

At least use the expression

```
1LL << 32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this, I should take a look at the current C Standard . IN the annotated ANSI C standard book that case isn't explicitly pointed out (Section 6.3.7 Bitwise shift operators).

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get the following representation: 00000001.00000000 (hexadecimal).

Do not use `int, long, long long` as their widths vary from platform to platform.  Use `(u)int32_t, (u)int64_t` for consistency.

`1 << 32` is `int` math - often too narrow for shifting 32 bits.  To form the binary value 1_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000, use `(u)int64_t` math.

Do not assume byte layout of wide integer types with code like `fractional_part = ((unsigned short int *) &varInit)[0];`.  Use math and let the compiler emit optimal code.

---

```
#include <stdint.h>

static int64_t varInit = ((int64_t)1) << 32;
// or 
static int64_t varInit = INT64_C(1) << 32;

int32_t integer_part = varInit >> 32;
uint32_t fractional_part = varInit & 0xFFFFFFFFu;
// or 
int32_t integer_part = varInit / 0x100000000;
uint32_t fractional_part = varInit % 0x100000000u;
```

Comment: Thanks @chux, great to see how it should be coded in a platform-independent way.